# Cannot take maximum value from sql table column

Tags: android, sqlite

```
          public Cursor selectRecords() {
          Cursor mCursor = database.query("prescritions" ,new String []{"MAX(pres_no)"},     null,    null, null, null,null);   


       if (mCursor != null) {  
        mCursor.moveToFirst();  


     }  
     return mCursor; // iterate to get each value.
}
```

I created above query to read maximum value from pres_no column reside in prescription table.But i get following error

```
  10-15 12:26:41.719: E/AndroidRuntime(629): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't       read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

Comment: why dont you write the sql query and use rawquery to execute it ?

Comment: use database.rawquery method..

Comment: Cursor mCursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(pres_no) from prescritions",null ); still get the same error

Comment: The error does not happen in the code you have shown.

Comment: You think you should use `mCursor.getCount()` instead of `mCursor!=NULL`. `query` returns a vaild `Cursor`, but with no data!

Answer (score 0):

`getColumnIndex` cannot work if you do not know the name of the column.
(And when you apply functions to a column, you result column name is not the table column name.)

In this query, the column you want is the first column, so you can drop the `getColumnIndex` call and simply use the column index (`0`) directly:

```java
cursor.getInteger(0)
```

Comment: it works fine.Can u explain little bit more cursor.getInteger(0) vsint data = cursor.getInt((cursor.getColumnIndex("pres_no")));

Comment: The *cursor* does not have a column named `pres_no` because you have not executed `SELECT pres_no FROM ...`.